# Allow outgoing connections using 'iptables'

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Greeting all,

"iptables -L" gives the following output

```
[root@ibmd ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Server has global IP and can be accessed from outer IPs.But I cannot ping nor telnet to any port (including TCP 80) from the server.
Does this has something to do with my 'iptables' settings ? Any tips on allow access from my server?

thanks in advance.

Comment: more appropiate to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an empty iptables, i.e. you have no firewall. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

May be the server ignore the packets of icmp,It may be the reason for the problem of 'ping'.

Has the server started the service of telnet?
you may try the command below to check the service port using tcp protocol.

```
netstat -lt
```

Is the 23 port keep the status of listening?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I had all traffic allowed in iptables and still wasn't able to reach any host (ping, telnet, ...). I've lost hours with trying to fix it in iptables, while the problem was default route. I had wrong (no) default gateway.

Take a look at

```
route -n -v
```